# My viewmodel collection isn't binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm at a loss for why this isn't working.

**Here's part of my model:**

```
public class AddComplianceReportViewModel 
{
    public PartyViewModel[] InvolvedParties { get; set; }
    public PartyViewModel[] ManagementParties { get; set; }
    public ConcealPartyViewModel[] ConcealParties { get; set; }

    public string ReportedByFirstName { get; set; }
    public string ReportedByLastName { get; set; }
    public string ReportedByBestTimeToContact { get; set; }
    public bool ReportedByRemainAnonymous { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    public string ReportedByPhone { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string ReportedByEmail { get; set; }

    public string GeneralDescription { get; set; }
    public string DetaledDescription { get; set; }
}

public class PartyViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ConcealPartyViewModel : PartyViewModel
{
    public string ConcealmentDescription { get; set; }
}
```

**Relevant code from my controller:**

```
[HttpGet, Route("report/new")]
public ViewResult FileReport()
{
    var vm = new AddComplianceReportViewModel()
    {
        ReportedByFirstName = "amy",
        ReportedByLastName = "lastname",
        ReportedByEmail = "my@email.com",
        ReportedByBestTimeToContact = "best time",
        ReportedByPhone = "555-123-4567",
        ReportedByRemainAnonymous = false,
        InvolvedParties = new []
        {
            new PartyViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = "saul",
                LastName = "goodman",
                Title = "lawyer"
            },
            new PartyViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = "walter",
                LastName = "white",
                Title = "cook"
            },
            new PartyViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = "jesse",
                LastName = "pinkman",
                Title = "lackey"
            }
        },
        ManagementParties = new PartyViewModel[]
        {
            new PartyViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = "Gus",
                LastName = "Freng",
                Title = "Boss"
            }
        },
        ConcealParties = new ConcealPartyViewModel[]
        {
            new ConcealPartyViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = "Skyler",
                LastName = "White",
                Title = "Wife",
                ConcealmentDescription = "money laundering"
            },
            new ConcealPartyViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = "Mike",
                LastName = "Ehrmantraut",
                Title = "Enforcer",
                ConcealmentDescription = "hid the bodies"
            }
        },

        GeneralDescription = "general description",
        DetaledDescription = "detailed description"
    };

    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost, Route("report/new", Name = RouteNames.PostReport)]
public ActionResult FileReport(AddComplianceReportViewModel vm)
{
    return View(vm);
}
```

I don't know if I need to share the views.  There's a lot of view code to pare down to the relevant bits.  I can add my views if needed.

This is the form data my browser is sending to the second controller method above:

> ReportedByFirstName=amy&ReportedByLastName=latname&ReportedByPhone=%28555%29+123-4567&ReportedByEmail=my%40email.com&ReportedByBestTimeToContact=best+time&%5B0%5D.FirstName=saul&%5B0%5D.LastName=goodman&%5B0%5D.Title=lawyer&%5B1%5D.FirstName=walter&%5B1%5D.LastName=white&%5B1%5D.Title=cook&%5B2%5D.FirstName=jesse&%5B2%5D.LastName=pinkman&%5B2%5D.Title=lackey&%5B0%5D.FirstName=Gus&%5B0%5D.LastName=Freng&%5B0%5D.Title=Boss&GeneralDescription=general+description&Duration=&AwarenessReason=&AwarenessReason=&%5B0%5D.FirstName=Skyler&%5B0%5D.LastName=White&%5B0%5D.Title=Wife&%5B0%5D.ConcealmentDescription=money+laundering&%5B1%5D.FirstName=Mike&%5B1%5D.LastName=Ehrmantraut&%5B1%5D.Title=Enforcer&%5B1%5D.ConcealmentDescription=hid+the+bodies

That's impossible to read, so here it is in an image provided by Fiddler (not all fields fit into image):

[image]

As you can see in the following image, none of the collections are populating:

[image]

What do I need to do for these to populate?  I'm at a loss.  I've noticed in the Fiddler screenshot that the party collections are ambiguous.  How do I tell MVC "this group is ConcealedParties, this group is ManagementParties", etc.?

**================== Per request, views================**

**_Parties.cshtml**

```
@model Redacted.Web.Models.Home.PartyViewModel[]

<div class="row">
    <div>@Html.Label("First Name")</div>
    <div>@Html.Label("Last Name")</div>
    <div>@Html.Label("Title")</div>
</div>

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns medium-1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="columns medium-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="columns medium-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="columns medium-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Title)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**The main view**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileReport", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Partial("_Parties", Model.InvolvedParties ?? new PartyViewModel[] { })
}
```

The `ManagementParties` collection is done the same way.  The `ConcealedParties` collection is has a different partial view, but the partial is loaded the same way.

Comment: Just post a part of a view where you are rendering inputs for one collection, say for ConcealedParties

Comment: @Andrei, I have updated the question with some of the views.

Comment: As an aside, if your app has a lot of forms or browser\server interaction, then this might be easier to develop as a single page app using either KnockoutJS + JQuery or  AnguarJS rather than using postbacks.

Comment: This app is a single form.  I'm using jQuery, it's just not included to keep the question a bit shorter.

Comment: I think I see what the problem is... in your form data the child items are listed as [0].FirstName, but they don't specify what property they belong to. I think they'd have to be something like "ConcealParties[0].FirstName".

Comment: Yeah, I think so too.  I don't know how to do that though.  My Google-fu has failed me today.

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ This looks like his sample project has something working in it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send your partial view your **entire** main model, then access the fields using that model. As you're not doing this, the names of your fields aren't correctly formed so model binding can't do it's thing.

See here (from your form data):

```
[0].FirstName
```

That should be:

```
InvolvedParties[0].FirstName
```

But it can't prefix with `InvolvedParties` because your partial view thinks that the top level model is the list itself, hence the omission of `InvolvedParties`.

Just another tip to prevent `null` collections in your models, just initialise them in the model constructor using coalesce:

```
public AddComplianceReportViewModel ()
{
    InvolvedParties = InvolvedParties ?? new PartyViewModel[] { };
}
```

Comment: I like this.  This is what I'm looking for.  But please look at the last part of my question.  I'm passing in the collections into the partial.  If I pass in the entire model, I won't be able to distinguish which collection I want to use in the partial.  Does that make sense?  Can I still reuse the same partial for each collection?

Comment: I'm accepting this.  Thank you very much!  I copied my `_Parties.cshtml` view to `_ManagementParties.cshtml` and have each one showing one of the collections.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Amy No problems, glad I could help.